# How to change the line color in seaborn lmplot

Tags: python, colors, seaborn

We can get a plot as bellow

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
sns.plt.show()
```

[image]

But when we have a lot of data points the regression line is not visible anymore. How can I change the line's color? I couldn't find anymore command

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can give arguments as key-value pairs (dictionary) to the underlying `plt.plot` and `plt.scatter` functions with `line_kws` and `scatter_kws`. So something like `line_kws = {'color': 'red'}` should do the job :

```
g = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip",
               data=tips, line_kws={'color': 'red'})
sns.plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the recommended approach from the documentation for legend items

```
g = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="smoker", data=tips,
               palette=dict(Yes="g", No="m"))
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but I landed here from google and it answered my question perfectly. How to give explicit colors to legend items without tinkering with palette.